# proving an equality of two sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x,y $ are real numbers, then

$$ (a,b) = \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} \left(a, b- \frac{1}{n} \right] \; \; $$

for large enough $N$.

#### TRY:

Say $x$ is in the union, then there is some $n_0 \geq N$ such that $ a < x \leq b - \frac{1}{n_0} $. I wanna show $x \in (a,b)$. Already I have $a < x$. I need to show $x < b$. If $x \geq b$, then $x \geq b \geq x + \frac{1}{n_0}$. this is contradiction since $1/n_0 > 0 $.

IS this correct? Also, how can I show that $(a,b)$ is contained in the union ?

Comment: Your attempt only includes one direction. Both directions of proof are required to establish equality between two sets. Can you include also your proof for the other direction (assume $x \in (a,b)$)?

Comment: You don't ned to use contradiction in that direction, since  $\,b-\dfrac1{n_0}<b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other direction: if $x \in (a,b) \to a < x < b \to \exists N: N(b-x) \geq 1$ by Archemedian Principle. Thus $\dfrac{1}{N} \leq b-x \to x \leq b - \dfrac{1}{N} \to x \in \left(a, b-\frac{1}{N}\right] \to x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=N}^\infty \left(a,b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

The phrase
"for large enough $N$"
in
$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} \left(a, b- \frac{1}{n} \right] $$
bothers me,
since,
for any $M \ge N$,
$\bigcup_{n=N}^{M} \left(a, b- \frac{1}{n} \right] 
=\left(a, b- \frac{1}{M} \right]
$.

To me,
this is asking to prove that
$(a, b)
=\lim\limits_{M \to \infty} \left(a, b- \frac{1}{M} \right]
$
and this is essentially
the same as proving that
$(a, b)
=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(a, b- \epsilon \right]
$.